# "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: endpoint" in Azure Data Factory V2

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am getting the following error when I execute Azure ML Batch Execution Activity in ADF V2.

[image: Error in ML Batch Execution Activity]

I have written following JSON query in ML Activity

```
{
    "name": "MLBatchExecution1",
    "description": "",
    "type": "AzureMLBatchExecution",
    "linkedServiceName": {
        "name": "AzureMLLinkedservice2",
        "type": "AzureML"
    },
    "typeProperties": {
        "webServiceInputs": {
            "input1": {
                "LinkedServiceName":{
                    "name": "azureblobstoragelinkedservice",
                    "type": "AzureStorage"
                }, 
                "FilePath":"tutoial/Input/TraiData.csv"
            }, 
            "input2": {
                "LinkedServiceName":{
                    "name": "azureblobstoragelinkedservice",
                    "type": "AzureStorage" 
                }, 
                "FilePath":"tutoial/Input/TestData.csv"
            }        
        },
        "webServiceOutputs": {
            "output1": {
                "LinkedServiceName":{
                    "name": "AzureStorageLinkedService2",
                    "type": "AzureStorage"   
                }, 
                "FilePath":"tutoial/Output/Output.csv"
            } 

        }
    }
}
```

I have make use of the following link to create linked service & activity:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-machine-learning

Can anyone help on this pls.
Any help will be appreciated..

Thanks

Deepak

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the argument when triggering the pipeline. The error you are receiving is because it enforces a parameter.